# What is the purpose of the Markov equation?

Tags: markov-chains, diophantine-equations

I am trying to do a research project for school on markov chains and Diophantine equations. I need to cite the significance of the study and the only place I can find any connection between the 2 is the markov equation. I have spent hours trying to find the purpose of the markov equation with no success.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Markov was involved in some very  different things. When you say Markov equation and Diophantine I think $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3 xyz$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_number

Comment: I see, your first question was similar

Comment: What is "the Markov equation"?

Answer (score 1):

See [1], [2] for applications of Diophantine approximation to Markov chains.

[1] Angel, Omer, Yuval Peres, and David B. Wilson. "Card shuffling and Diophantine approximation." The Annals of Applied Probability 18, no. 3 (2008): 1215-1231.  https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-applied-probability/volume-18/issue-3/Card-shuffling-and-Diophantine-approximation/10.1214/07-AAP484.short

[2] Boczkowski, L., Peres, Y., & Sousi, P. (2018). Sensitivity of mixing times in Eulerian digraphs. SIAM Journal on Discrete Mathematics, 32(1), 624-655.  https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/16M1073376

Comment: Hi Yuval, This [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4597015/121671) might be interesting to you. I have tried it myself by just taking the Hahn decomposition of the measure $\mu-\nu-(\mu-\nu)_+-(\mu-\nu)_-$ and trying to mach terms but have not succeeded yet.